# How do i arrange into swimlanes

Tags: ruby, database, multithreading, algorithm

I am trying to arrange 10000 events into different lanes. Each event has a start and end date. No events can overlap in a lane.

```
    ======================================================================
Lane 1   [Event1]      [Event4       ]  [Event7   ]
    ======================================================================
    ======================================================================
Lane 2         [Event2]            [Event 5]      [Event 8]
    ======================================================================
    ======================================================================
Lane 3     [Event3        ]       [Event6]      
    ======================================================================
    ========time along x axis        >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
```

So my problem is identifying the appropriate lane for an event efficiently. I get the events sorted by start time from the database. The first approach I took is have a last_end_time for each lane. For every new event I check with each lane and if the start_time of the event is prior to the last_end_time of the lane, I move down and check the next lane. And if I do not find a lane where I can fit it in, I create a new lane.

```
class LaneManager
  def initialize
    @lanes = []
  end

  # Find the free lane given start and end of an event
  def nextFreeLane start_date, end_date
    @lanes.each_with_index do |lane, index|
      if start_date > lane.last_date
        lane.last_date = end_date
        return index
      end
    end
    lane = Lane.new
    lane.last_date = end_date
    @lanes << lane
    @lanes.length - 1
  end
end

class Lane
  attr_accessor :last_date
end
```

This however suffers from another problem. If I have 5000 events with the same start and end, then to find a slot for the 5001 event, I end up checking the previous 5000 lanes and so on.. and the performance just degrades.

Any suggestions on how to store, query the events efficiently? I need to render them on a webpage. I have horizontal and vertical scrolling to pan across events. For vertical scrolling I tell my server - these are the lanes I need (say lane 5 to lane 10). For horizontal scrolling I just make a new query with the new time window and lanes needed which is basically new set of events.

My problem is the vertical scrolling, I need to efficiently slot all the events into the correct lane. If I can do that efficiently then I can just query my server for the events in lanes say 26-30. Will be grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Your illustration of 5000 events is not Schlemiel's problem, but merely a bad and presumably, very unlikely input case.

Comment: @BorisStitnicky my current dataset is giving me this problem. That said I should remove the reference. It just distracts from the main problem. It still is inefficient. Is there some quicksort kind of algorithm that I could do?

Comment: Your problem is basically solvable by the greedy approach. The only caveat is what you say, if you have run-ins of many events in the same time frame.

Comment: Is it an option to store the lane as you go, or are the specs so that this isn't reasonable?

Comment: @Denis I don't think I can figure the lane as I go.. I fetch the events sorted by start time. Since I do not wish to send the user all 10k events (just slows it down UX wise), I am looking to identify what will fit in the viewing area - specifically about 5 lanes he can see and the time window that he has selected.

Comment: @Sudhir: yeah, hence my question. Is it an option to set the lane once and for all, or is it not? A simple self-join can yield the number of possible concurrent lanes being used for a given event, giving you a range of possible lane numbers. But this is still an indeterminate solution, in the sense that to need a known starting point. If the starting point is stored, it's easy; if not, you need to revisit the lane assignment up to a point in time where there are no events at all -- possibly up to the origin of time.

Answer (score 2):

First, pour the beginning and ending times together into one set, and sort by time. For every ending, find the nearest next beginning, and make a link to it. Once you are finished, unravel the threads: Take the first beginning and take it away from the bundle along with the whole chain of events linked to it (remember that each end is linked to the nearest beginning). Repeat the process until no event beginnings (and thus, no events) are left in the bundle.

Comment: Interesting approach. Will try and update. Thx. Thinking of moving the logic to a stored proc if it is efficient enough.

Answer (score 2):

I'll expand on my comment's question as an answer, since it's too long with sample data.

Sample data is:

```
create table events (
    id          serial primary key,
    startend    tsrange not null
);

insert into events (startend)
select tsrange(now()::timestamp(0) + i * interval '1 minute', now()::timestamp(0) + i * interval '1 minute 30 second' + (i % 6) * interval '10 second')
from generate_series(1,100) i;
```

A simple join such as this one:

```
with events as (
select  evt.id as evt_id,
        evt.startend as evt_startend,
        chk.id as chk_id,
        chk.startend as chk_startend
from    events evt
join    events chk on evt.startend && chk.startend
)
select  *
from events
order by evt_startend, chk_startend
limit 10;
```

Yields something like the following set:

```
 evt_id |                 evt_startend                  | chk_id |                 chk_startend                  
--------+-----------------------------------------------+--------+-----------------------------------------------
      1 | ["2013-06-24 15:03:27","2013-06-24 15:04:07") |      1 | ["2013-06-24 15:03:27","2013-06-24 15:04:07")
      2 | ["2013-06-24 15:04:27","2013-06-24 15:05:47") |      2 | ["2013-06-24 15:04:27","2013-06-24 15:05:47")
      2 | ["2013-06-24 15:04:27","2013-06-24 15:05:47") |      3 | ["2013-06-24 15:05:27","2013-06-24 15:07:27")
      3 | ["2013-06-24 15:05:27","2013-06-24 15:07:27") |      2 | ["2013-06-24 15:04:27","2013-06-24 15:05:47")
      3 | ["2013-06-24 15:05:27","2013-06-24 15:07:27") |      3 | ["2013-06-24 15:05:27","2013-06-24 15:07:27")
      3 | ["2013-06-24 15:05:27","2013-06-24 15:07:27") |      4 | ["2013-06-24 15:06:27","2013-06-24 15:09:07")
      4 | ["2013-06-24 15:06:27","2013-06-24 15:09:07") |      3 | ["2013-06-24 15:05:27","2013-06-24 15:07:27")
      4 | ["2013-06-24 15:06:27","2013-06-24 15:09:07") |      4 | ["2013-06-24 15:06:27","2013-06-24 15:09:07")
      4 | ["2013-06-24 15:06:27","2013-06-24 15:09:07") |      5 | ["2013-06-24 15:07:27","2013-06-24 15:10:47")
      4 | ["2013-06-24 15:06:27","2013-06-24 15:09:07") |      6 | ["2013-06-24 15:08:27","2013-06-24 15:11:27")
(10 rows)
```

As you can see in the above, for any given event, you can readily pin down the potential number of concurrent events (the column to the right where a given ) and thus the potential lane number for a given event. However, it is only a range: for any given row id to the right, there are multiple possibilities of seeding the lane number to the left.

A somewhat ugly query with some window functions can likely let you determine when the lane number needs to be reset. The problem is, reset to what?...

The only way to know the latter is to identify a point in time with no events at all (in which case lane = 1). For any other point in time, the best you can tell is that there's a free lane, or that you need to create a new lane.

As a result, and assuming this is an option for you, I'd advise to actually store the lane number, and to generate it automatically using a trigger. Within the trigger, a simple query for concurrent events yields a list of busy lanes, allowing you to safely pick or create one that isn't busy -- or lane 1 if no lane is assigned at that point of time.

Your schema would then look more like this:

```
create table events (
    id          serial primary key,
    startend    tsrange not null,
    lane        int not null
);
```

And the query for horizontal and vertical scrolling become trivial.

Comment: Thanks @Denis . I have done an initial implementation based on a SortedSet of Lanes (sorted by last_event_end_time and position). I will see how that goes. The performance is acceptable. Had to deal with a nasty default implementation of SortedSet in Ruby though. Will update. Many thanks for your time.

Answer (score 1):

This is known as Interval Partitioning or Interval Graph Coloring. See for example [here](http://www.cs.umd.edu/class/fall2009/cmsc451/lectures/Lec04-interval.pdf). Your approach is almost identical to the optimal algorithm, except that you need to start with the correct number of lanes instead of adding them as needed. To implement it efficiently, keep a set of currently free lanes (e.g. as a balanced search tree) and update it when intervals start or end.